# Invoke right-click menu in a process in windows c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell, winapi

I have spent last 3 days trying to find a solution on the net and by myself. Found lots of relevant material but nothing would fit my scenario.
I have started a new process by the following code, it is the windows speech recognition app, I want to programatically invoke one of the the options in its right click menu.

I have already tested 
Postmessage, Sendmessage and sendClick events, none of them work.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClass, string lpW);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern void PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            const int WM_COMMAND = 0x0111; 
            Process proc = new Process();

            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessibility\Speech Recognition.lnk";

            proc.Start(); 
            Thread.Sleep(200);   
            IntPtr Window = FindWindow(null, "Speech Recognition");

            SetForegroundWindow(Window);

            SendKeys.SendWait("{Move 200,200}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of trying to 'click' that context menu option, does the speech app have any public api to access the 'Speech Dictionary', have you tried invoking it other ways? Not sure if thats plausible or not

Comment: Use the official automation interface when trying to automate a GUI: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to `Open the Speech Dicitonary` you can do it by

- Running command line: `SpeechUXWiz.exe VocabularyManager`
- Using API: [Add new word to windows speech recognition using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546087/add-new-word-to-windows-speech-recognition-using-c-sharp)

  > You'll need to use the [SAPI Automation APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (aka SpeechLib) to
  >   access the [ISpLexicon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interfaces.
  >
  > In particular, [`ISpLexicon::AddPronunciation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee450824%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will add a new word
  >   (and its associated pronunciation) to the user lexicon.

Comment: `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SpSharedRecoContext ssrc = new SpSharedRecoContext();
            ISpeechRecognizer ispSpeechReco = ssrc.Recognizer;
    
            if (ispSpeechReco.IsUISupported("AddRemoveWord", null))
            {
             ispSpeechReco.DisplayUI(this.Handle.ToInt32(), "Additional Training", "AddRemoveWord", "");
            }`

I am using the following to show the AddRemove UI, but it crashes with a COM error, any ideas?